# implementing GCM communication

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement `GCM` communication in order to create `push notifications`, from my application server to all the devices that my app is installed  via `GOOGLE's servers`.

I have found a library that helps me do this the `Parse library` and using the dashboard given I've sent a push notification from server to device and vice-versa.

The thing is that  I want to be able to use the push notification (server side) from my website and not having to log in in Parse's. I'm pretty clueless about this, So I'd appreciate any direction and suggestion given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  may start with these tutorial

Using **asp.net**

[**Redth/PushSharp**](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp)  - A server-side library for sending Push Notifications to iOS (iPhone/iPad APNS), Android (C2DM and GCM - Google Cloud Message), Windows Phone, Windows 8, Amazon, Blackberry, and (soon) FirefoxOS devices!

[Push Messages to GCM server using visual c#.net application (server side).](http://www.tejaprakash.com/2013/05/push-messages-to-gcm-server-using-net.html)

And using  **PHP and MySQL**

[Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

And using **Parse API**

if you want to send pushnotification from parse API (not dashboard) then see
[Push Notification Guide](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide)

Comment: Just a question for that Parse API, Can I write a ,let's say, php script using the API so that it runs on the server sending automatically they pushes for my applications?

Comment: @libathos I did not use PHP with parse,but it should be.

Answer (score 0):

There are docs in Parse for sending push notification from Ios,Android,.net,Javascript,php and REST services, use one them which is appropriate for you.

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/JavaScript